# Why does it takes so long to add PSObject to ArrayList in Powershell? Any better approach?

Tags: .net, performance, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have the following code

```
$listA = *some list of 1000 items*
$listB = *other list*

$newList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach($a in $listA) {
    $b = get somevalue from list $listB
    $temp = New-Object PSObject
    $temp | Add-Member Name $a
    $temp | Add-Member Age $b
    $newList.Add($temp) | Out-Null
}
```

I tested the performance with Simple arrays as well which is worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your performance issue is not the arralist, but your object creation.

Building objects with `Add-Member` is a V1 construct and is actually the least efficient way to create objects.  Every `Add-Member` results in destroying the original object and creating a brand new one.  Since you've tagged the question with V3, here's a much better (faster) method for creating objects:

```
$listA = *some list of 1000 items*
$listB = *other list*

$newList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach($a in $listA) {
    $b = get somevalue from list $listB
    $Object = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name = $a
    Age = $b
    }
  $newList.Add($Object)

 }
```